# PHP: Webservice error SoapClient

Tags: php

Request from SoapUI

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:not="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <not:SaasNotificationResponse>
         <hostID>UCALL</hostID>
         <orderID>1180000335810000000010</orderID>
         <custID>1180000335770000000010</custID>
         <typeTransaction>SUSPENSION</typeTransaction>
         <status>3</status>
         <message>SUSPENSION 1180000335770000000010</message>
         <notifyAttr>
            <name>?</name>
            <value>?</value>
         </notifyAttr>
      </not:SaasNotificationResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response From SoapUI:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:SaasNotificationResponseResponse xmlns:ns2="http://xxx.xxxx.xxx.com/">
         <return>F</return>
         <return>Invalid TypeTransaction</return>
      </ns2:SaasNotificationResponseResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

---

Codding PHP Client;

```
require_once('lib/nusoap.php'); 
try {
    $client = new SoapClient("http://xxx.xxx.xxx/Notification?WSDL");       
    $data =  array( 'hostID' => 'UCALL',
         'orderID' => '1180000335810000000010',
         'custID' => '1180000335810000000010',
         'typeTransaction' => 'ACTIVATION',
         'status' => '3',
         'message' => 'Activation complete',
         'notifyAttr' => array(
            array('name'=>'AccountID','value'=>'110022101010'),
            array('name'=>'PackageID','value'=>'1')
          )  
);

    $return=$client->SaasNotificationResponse($data);
    //$return=$client->call('SaasNotificationResponse',($data));        
    print_r($return);       
 }catch (SoapFault $e){
    echo $e;
}
```

> Error Application.
>   **Fatal error: Call to undefined method soapclient::SaasNotificationResponse() in C:\wamp\www\spgdtws\notification.php**

I have a problem in php webservice applications. if using soapUI. webservice server can be invoked. but when I use the application on the client. error occurs. please help

Comment: check the path of soap class

Comment: Does this work? $client->__soapCall("SaasNotificationResponse", $data);

Comment: try this `$client->__getFunctions();` to check `SaasNotificationResponse` method is exist or not.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method soapclient::__soapCall() in C:\wamp\www\spgdtws\notification.php on line 19

Comment: Why nusoap? Did you try PHP internal SoapClient?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are calling notification WSDL for Telkom's service. 
this code works for me

```
<?php
function sendNotification($orderID,$custID,$typeTransaction,$status,$message) {
    try {
        $client = new SoapClient("XXXXXXXXX/Notification?wsdl",array("trace"=>1,"exceptions"=>1));

        $data =  array( 'hostID' => '',
                'orderID' => $orderID,
                'custID' => $custID,
                'typeTransaction' => $typeTransaction,
                'status' => $status,
                'message' => $message,
                'notifyAttr' => array(
                    array('name'=>'','value'=>''),
                    array('name'=>'','value'=>'')
                )             
         );


        $return=$client->SaasNotificationResponse($data);

    var_dump($return);

    }catch (SoapFault $e){
        echo $e;
    }
}
sendNotification('1180000339980000000010','4720562','TERMINATION','3','TERMINATION success');

?>
```

You don't need to include nusoap. Use native PHP's SOAP instead. SoapClient class is belong to native PHP.

for reference : 
http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php