# PHP SoapClient - Call to undefined function

Tags: php, soap

I have this code:

```
<?php
$login = '';
$password = '';
$session = new SoapClient("https://mybilling.telinta.com/wsdl/SessionAccountService.wsdl");

echo '<pre>';
print_r($session->__getFunctions());
$session_id = $session−>login($login, $password);
```

And this gives me this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => int ping(string $session_id)
    [1] => string logout(string $session_id)
    [2] => string login(string $user, string $password)
)


Fatal error:  Call to undefined function login() in C:\.... on line 14
```

Why error is produced ?

Comment: The code works on my pc. I could not find any error.

Comment: I find error, problem is that I copy code from pdf and some invisible character was before "l" in login.

Comment: From here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102422/php-webservice-error-soapclient:

Try this:
`$session->__soapCall("login", $data);`

Where `$data` is an array containing the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when Soap was not enabled on php.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-soap 
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

change 7.4 to your version
or
for other ways to enable Soap look [stack over flow enable soap question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584426/how-do-i-enable-enable-soap-in-php-on-linux)